# ASP.NET MVC - Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection

I am going over dependency injection.  I have an ASP.NET MVC project where the model is named Customers:

```
public class Customers
{
    public ID get; set; 
    private Customer customer

    public Customers()
    {
       customer = new Customer(); 
    }
}
```

Now I am suppose to add classes in order to eliminate the dependency in the above class.  For example, Customer is a dependency of the Customers class.
Customers should depend on an abstraction.  I created an interface (or abstract class) named IStorageCustomer

```
public interface IStorageCustomer 
{
}
```

Now I changed the Customers class to the following below:

```
public class Customers
{
    public ID get; set; 
    private IStorageCustomer customer;

    public Customers(IStorageCustomer customer)
    {
       this.customer = customer; 
    }
}
```

I need to know if the dependency has been eliminated in the above class.  What else do I need to do?  Please help.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What role do the `Customers` and `Customer` classes play in your application?

Comment: What do you mean by role? Can you give me an example?

Comment: What do those classes do? Is `Customer` an entity? Does `Customers` allow loading entities from the database?

Comment: Your example and naming are unclear. Why does a Customers (plural) class have a Customer (singular) property? Why does it have an Id?

Comment: In the MVC world you would have a CustomerController with an injected dependency on a repository or a service.

Comment: I have renamed Customer to Person instead.  Person has a field and it is using System.Data.Entity

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ninject MVC. (be aware there are different version for each version of MVC)

This is a Nuget which manages the dependency Injection for you.

To make Ninject inject the right class, you should set it up in the NinjectWebCommon file.

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    //all your bindings will be configured here
    kerenl.Bind<IStorageCustomer>().To<Costumer>(); //if you want Customer instances to be injected everywhere you expect an IStorageCustomer
}
```

Also leave a default constructor for the class you want to inject instances into.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Customer, I will rename it to Person.  Now here are the changes that I have so far.  This is also including classes that I have just added.  The only problem is that person in the Customers model class is inaccessible because it is private and also its type.

```
public class Customers
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    private IStoragePerson person;

    public Customers()
    {
        this.person = LocateCustomer.GetCustomer();
    }
}

public class Person : IStoragePerson
{
    public string person{ get; set; }
}
```

Don't know what to add for IStoragePerson

```
public interface IStoragePerson
{
}

public class LocateCustomer
{
    public static IStoragePerson person{ get; set; }
    public static IStoragePerson GetCustomer()
    {
        if(person == null)
        {
            person = new Person();
        }
        return person;
    }
}
```